# How to access a text file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a jquery ajax call to the following text file:

```
sport=Table Tennis&groups=no&no_groups=&grp_names=&teams=1^China^6157~2^Finland^6158~3^Sweden^6159~4^Japan^6149~5^Korea^6154&Endstr=End
```

The call is working fine. But I really don't know how to access a particular value like lets say, 'China' from the above text file? I am trying tis for the first time. please help..

Comment: "China" does not seem to have a value, it’s just a part of the team string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to parse your data. It would have been straight forward if you have chosen JSON as return data.

```
function myParser() {

    var str = "sport=Table Tennis&groups=no&no_groups=&grp_names=&teams=1^China^6157~2^Finland^6158~3^Sweden^6159~4^Japan^6149~5^Korea^6154&Endstr=End";
    var arPairs = str.split("&");
    var outObj = {};
    for (var i=0; i < arPairs.length; i++) {
      var arTemp = arPairs[i].split("=");
      var key = arTemp[0];
      var value = arTemp[1];
      if (key === "teams") {
        arTemp = value.split("~");
        var teamObj = {};
        for (var j=0; j < arTemp.length; j++) {
          var arTeamData = arTemp[j].split("^");
          teamObj[arTeamData[1]] = arTeamData[2];
        }
        value = teamObj;
      }
      outObj[key] = value;
    }
    return outObj;
}
```

output: Is an array having all your data available. You can refer it as:

var outObj = myParser();
console.log(outObj.sport); // Prints "Table Tennis"
console.log(outObj.teams.china) // Prints china data

Comment: thanks..but as you said it prints the china data..i.e. _6157_ and not the name 'china'..any way i can do it?

Comment: Yes, just do for (var teamName in outObj.teams) {

Comment: You can also change my code (teamObj[arTeamData[1]] = arTeamData[2];) to insert into an array if you wish. I used object for quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the `parseParams` plugin](https://gist.github.com/956897) which you can use to split a querystring into an array.

You can use it like this:

```
var querystring = 'sport=Table Tennis&groups=no&no_groups=&grp_names=&teams=1^China^6157~2^Finland^6158~3^Sweden^6159~4^Japan^6149~5^Korea^6154&Endstr=End';
var paramsObj = $.parseParams(querystring);
alert(paramsObj.sport); // = Table Tennis
```

Comment: thanks its working..but still i cant access a particular value like china as i said earlier..  alert(paramsObj.teams); will display the entire teams string..

Comment: That's correct. `China` is part of the value - which could conceivably change. You would need to split the value to get the part you want.

Comment: And that's why people invented JSON :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't use such file structure. Use JSON instead. i.e:

```
{
   "sport":"Table Tennis",
   "groups":false,
   "no_groups":"",
   "grp_names":[

   ],
   "teams":[
      {
         "China":6157
      },
      {
         "Finland":6158
      },
      {
         "Sweden":6159
      },
      {
         "Japan":6149
      },
      {
         "Korea":6154
      }
   ],
   "Endstr":"End"
}
```

Then, after you parse it with $.get or $.ajax, you just access:

```
data.sports
```

for example.